# M2e run on server maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I don't see "run on server" option for maven project/module. I have installed Maven Integration for Eclipse and Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP. I am using Tomcat v.7.0. What should I do ?

Comment: I have the same question.